# Mocha tests failing when mongod running with auth=true

Tags: mongodb, testing, mongoose, mocha.js

I'm trying to setup Mocha testing some simple crud stuff on NodeJS to MongoDB via MongooseJS.

The tests all work fine (and pass) if I have mongod running with auth=false

However, if I run mongod with auth=true everything fails, even if I'm specifying the username and password in the URI like this:

```
mongodb://thisIsMyUsername:thisIsMyPassword@127.0.0.1/theDataBaseName
```

Any ideas as to why this fails?

Is it not possible to test against a Mongo database which requires authentication?

Comment: What is the failure, exactly?

Comment: I get: `MongoError: need to login` on the connection and then `Error: unauthorized db:thedatabasename-test ns:cupid-test.collectionname lock type:0 client:127.0.0.1`